# How to count how many times a number occurs in a very large number

Tags: python, count

value = 12343211122321
print(value.count(1))

The count() function does not tell me how many time the number 1 is in the value variable.
What do I have to do?

Comment: Does a count() function only work for strings?

Comment: Converting the number to a string seems like what you want to do. Mathematically, 1 occurs 12343211122321 times in your `value`.

Comment: Maybe you mean how many *digits*?

Comment: Isn't this what you expect? - 
`"12343211122321".count("1")` or `str(12343211122321).count("1")` results in `5`.

Comment: Numbers don't occur inside each other.

Comment: @DanielHao yes i meant digit.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like `print(str(value).count('1'))` as `count()` is a method of `str` or `list` objects (and not `int`)